# Applying tabs with views and not separate activities

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to convert my current tab setup to one that uses views and not seperate activities... I have issues with calling my search function and I think it is due to the way I have created my tabs.

My main launcher activity is `public class Menu extends TabActivity` which creates the tabs

```
 intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabGroup1.class);
 // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
 spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("codes").setIndicator("All Codes",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_codes))
 .setContent(intent);
 tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

`TabGroup1' does the following for each tab

```
public class TabGroup1 extends TabGroupActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startChildActivity("Category", new Intent(this,Category.class));
}
}
```

Which then calls the `ListActivity` which shows the content from there when an item is clicked another intent is created which then starts a new activity which allows me to have the tabs on each level as the user goes down the lists.

This is done with the following code

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), SubCategory.class);
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("CATEGORY", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    /*startActivity(intent);*/
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
    parentActivity.startChildActivity("SubCategory", intent);
}
```

`TabGroupActivity` is a class which I found from a [tutorial](http://ericharlow.blogspot.ca/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) that allows you to have multiple activities under the same tab layout.

What I am struggling is with converting what I have to using views and using setContent to change the views.

I have found [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab/) example but it doesn't provide enough detail for me to go on.
Also found [this](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=5424397F3130CE7769FF47DD67742911?recipeId=1693&recipeFrom=ViewTOC) one as well...

Can someone please provide me the run down on what I need to change and also how do I setContent using my listactivities...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused... you are creating new tabs every time you change tabs currently????

Comment: Hi @Barak I have editted my question above with some further code for how each activity calls upon the next one so that the tabs are on the top...it works but I want to convert from this because I have read that it isn't the best method and that ActivityGroup is deprecated. This [tutorial](http://ericharlow.blogspot.ca/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) is the one I used to create my tabs.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things... setContent defines the content, it doesn't cause the switching of tabs.  If you want to force a change to a certain tab you use `TabHost.setCurrentTab(tabid);`, otherwise it defaults to the first tab, then whatever the user chooses.

An example from one of my own projects (This project actually has four tabs, but I've cut out some to try and keep this to the point).  There are several ways to do it, but I found the easiest was to create a method to populate each tab, that way I could refresh a tab as needed by calling the appropriate method for whichever tab I needed (all of the java below is contained in the TabActivity).

**setupdetailmain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/setupheader"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom" />
            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp" >
            <!-- General Info Tab -->
                    <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/note_tab"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >
                    </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Tool Tab -->
                    <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/offset_tab"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >
                            <ListView
                                    android:id="@+id/list2"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
                    </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**tab setup code (extends TabActivity)**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setupdetailmain);

    // ***************************************************************
    // Set up the tabs in the tabhost
    // ***************************************************************
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Offsets").setIndicator("Offsets")
            .setContent(R.id.offset_tab);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Notes").setIndicator("Notes")
            .setContent(R.id.note_tab);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    populateTabs(StartTab);
}
```

**tab populate methods**

```
// ***************************************************************
// Fill the Notes tab
// ***************************************************************
private void notestab() {
    notes = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.note_tab);
    notestxt = new TextView(this);
    notestxt.setText(SETUPINFO_NOTES);
    notestxt.setTextSize(15);
    notes.addView(notestxt);
}

// ***************************************************************
// Fill the Offset tab
// ***************************************************************
private void offsettab() {
    wpccount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (wpcdesc[i] != null) {
            wpcdisplayhold[wpccount] = wpcid[i] + " - " + wpcdesc[i];
            wpcidhold[wpccount] = wpcid[i];
            wpcdeschold[wpccount] = wpcdesc[i];
            wpccount++;
        }
    }
    wpcdisplay = new String[wpccount];
    for (int i = 0; i < wpccount; i++) {
        wpcdisplay[i] = wpcdisplayhold[i];
    }
    mWPCView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    mWPCView.setAdapter(new ColorizingListAdapter(SetupDisplay.this,
            wpcdisplay, "Offset"));
    registerForContextMenu(mWPCView);
}
```

This uses a custom adapter, but hopefully it gets across the idea of how to set up your lists in a tab view without doing a new activity.